# I need to redirect homepage to one domain and rest of the pages to another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect my domain www.example.com to www.new-example.com but only if the user requests the root. If its a subpage, then I need it to go to a subdomain.

Example: www.example.com/ -> www.new-example.com/
         www.example.com/p1.html -> example.new-example.com/p1

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.new-example.com/ [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.new-example.com/$1 [L,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava it worked great. I add made a rule to the root but was having troubles creating the second rule.

Comment: I have a problem in the redirects. If something is passed as www.example.com/?param=1 it shoud go to example.new-example.com/?param=1 but it goes to www.new-example.com/?param=1